# python memory overhead from calling functions/methods

Tags: python, performance, function, optimization, methods

It makes code cleaner and easier to read / work-with when things are nicely divided into functions.  Is there any memory usage overhead to passing (large) objects back and forth between different method calls?  i.e.

Model 1 - Unified:

```
data1 = getData("1")
# Do stuff to data1
# ...
saveData(data1)

data2 = getData("2")
# Do stuff to data2
# ...
saveData(data2)
```

Model 2 - Divided:

```
def doStuff(dat):
    # Do stuff to data
    # ...
    return dat

data1 = getData("1")
data1 = doStuff(data1)
saveData(data1)
data2 = getData("2")
data2 = doStuff(data2)
saveData(data2)
```

Comment: There is some minor overhead for every function call.  The size of the objects being passed around does not matter whatsoever.

Comment: In Python, objects and such are passed by reference, not by value, so the I believe the overhead should be about the same regardless of the size of the object you pass in.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is, but unless you're doing something crazy it should be tiny relative to the rest of your program, on the scale of multiple kilobytes.